# Finding $x+y$, given $xy= 1$, $x^2+y^2=5$, $x^3+y^3=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, factoring, nonlinear-system

This problem is from a math competition, but I think is wrong:

> Find the value of $x+y$ if:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> xy &= 1 \\ 
> x^2 + y^2 &= 5 \\ 
> x^3+y^3 &= 8
> \end{align}$$

Solution (I think is wrong):

$x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)(x^2-xy+y^2) = (x+y)(5-1) = 4(x+y)$

So we have:

$x^3+y^3 = 4(x+y)$

$x^3+y^3 = 8$

Then:

$8 = 4(x+y)$

$x+y = 2$

However if we replace that value in $(x+y)^2$ we have:

$(x+y)^2 = 2^2 =4$

$(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2+2xy = 5 + 2 = 7$

As you can see $4 \neq 7$, what is happening?

Comment: If you graph the three curves you will see that there are no points where all the curves intersect.

Comment: Eliminating $x$ and $y$ from the system $xy=a$, $x^2+y^2=b$, $x^3+y^3=c$ gives the necessary condition $$a \left((a-b)^2 (2a+b)-c^2\right)=0$$ This is not satisfied for $a=1$, $b=5$, $c=8$.

Comment: It is a bit peculiar that the phrasing of the competition problem would _suggest_ that the system of equations has a solution.  There must have been people tearing their hair out wondering where their mistakes were...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us call $a := x + y$ and $b := xy$. Then the proposed system of equations is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
b = 1\\\\
a^{2} - 2b = 5\\\\
a^{3} - 3ab = 8
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
b = 1\\\\
a^{2} = 7\\\\
a^{3} - 3a = 8
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
b = 1\\\\
a = \pm\sqrt{7}\\\\
a = 2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
which clearly has no solutions. I think this answers your question about what is happening.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The following method has the advantage that it can be generalized
for similar kinds of problems with more variables.

Consider the equation satisfied by $\;z=x\;$ and $\;z=y\;$
$$ z^2 - (x+y)z + (xy) = (z-x)(z-y) = 0. \tag1 $$
Then for all integer $n\ge 0$ it is true that
$$ z^{n+2} - (x+y)z^{n+1} + (xy)z^n = 0. \tag2 $$
Substitute $x$ and $y$ for $z$ in this equation and add the two equations to get
$$ (x^{n+2} + y^{n+2}) - (x+y)(x^{n+1} + y^{n+1}) + (x^n + y^n) = 0. \tag3 $$
Define $\;c := x^1+y^1 = x+y \;$ and note that $\;x^0 + y^0 = 2.\;$
Now assume that
$$ x\,y = 1, \quad x^2 + y^2 = 5, \quad \text{ and } \quad x^3 + y^3 = 8. \tag4 $$
Use equation $(3)$  with $\;n=1,\;n=0\;$ and assumptions $(4)$ to get
$$ 8 - c\,5 + c = 0 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad 5 - c\,c + 2 = 0. \tag5 $$
The equation for $\;n=1\;$ implies that $\;c=2\;$ but this is inconsistent
with the equation for $\;n=0.\;$

Thus the assumptions in $(4)$ are inconsistent and there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

Let $z = (x + y)$. 
The following equations **over-determine** the value of $z$.

- E-1: $~x^2 + y^2 = 5.$
- E-2: $xy = 1.$
- E-3: $x^3+y^3 = 8.$

Since $~z^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy,~$ 
E-1,E-2 collectively imply that 
$\displaystyle z^2 = 7 ~\implies~  z ~\in ~\left\{+\sqrt{7}, -\sqrt{7}\right\}.$

So, $\displaystyle ~~\left\{+\sqrt{7}, -\sqrt{7}\right\}~$ are the only candidate values for $z$.

Since $z^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3xy(z)$, 
E-2,E-3 collectively imply that $z^3 = 8 + 3z \implies z^3 - 3z - 8.$

Trying each candidate value in turn gives:

- $\displaystyle \left[+\sqrt{7}\right]^3 - 3\left[+\sqrt{7}\right] = 4\sqrt{7} \neq 8.$
- $\displaystyle \left[-\sqrt{7}\right]^3 - 3\left[-\sqrt{7}\right] = -4\sqrt{7} \neq 8.$

So, neither of the two candidate values collectively implied by E-1 and E_2, satisfy the constraint collectively implied by E-2 and E-3.

Answer (score 1):

We can also take a geometric interpretation of the problem. The curves corresponding to the equations

$$ xy \  = \  1 \ \ \ , \ \ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \   = \  5 \ \ \ , \ \ \ x^3 \ + \ y^3  \  = \  8 $$

all have symmetry about the line $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ (only the first two, however, has symmetry about the origin).  This suggests an approach in which we look at intersections of these curves with lines through the origin $ \ y \ = \ mx \ \ . \ $  (We do not need to consider a "horizontal" or "vertical" line, since the first curve has the coordinates axes as asymptotes.)  If there  are value(s) of $ \ m \ $ which "work" for all three curves, then we have located their mutual intersections.

With this substitution, we have
$$ m·x^2 \  = \  1 \ \ \ , \ \ \ (1 + m^2)·x^2  \   = \  5 \ \ \ , \ \ \ (1 + m^3)·x^3  \  = \  8 \ \ . $$
For the first two curve equations, we obtain
$$  (1 + m^2)·\frac{1}{m}  \ \  = \ \ 5 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ m^2 - 5m + 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ m \ \ = \ \ \frac{5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{21}}{2} \ \ . $$
(As $ \ \frac{2}{5 \ +\ \sqrt{21}} \ = \ \frac{2·(5 \ - \ \sqrt{21})}{25 - 21} \ = \ \frac{5 \ - \ \sqrt{21}}{2} \ \ , \ $ we see that these lines are indeed symmetrical about $ \ y \ = \ x \ \ . \   $   These slopes also tell us that the circle and rectangular hyperbola intersect only in the first and third quadrants.)

*However,* in the third equation, this gives us
$$ (1 + m^3)·\left( \frac{1}{m} \right)^{3/2}  \ \  \stackrel{?}{=} \  \   8  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (1 + m^3)   \ \  \stackrel{?}{=} \  \   8· m^{3/2}  \ \  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left( \ 1 \ + \ \left[ \ \frac{5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{21}}{2} \ \right]^3 \ \right)   \ \  \stackrel{?}{=} \  \   8· \left[ \ \frac{5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{21}}{2} \ \right]^{3/2} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \ 8 \ + \  \ ( \ 5^3 \ \pm \ 3·5^2·\sqrt{21} \ + \ 3·5·21 \ \pm \ 21^{3/2} \ )    \ \  \stackrel{?}{=} \  \   16·\sqrt2· ( \ 5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{21} \ )^{3/2} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \ 8 \ + \  \ ( \ 440 \ \pm \ 96·\sqrt{21} \  \ )    \ \  \stackrel{?}{=} \  \   16·\sqrt2· ( \ 5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{21} \ )^{3/2} $$
[then, squaring both sides]
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \ ( \ 448 \   \pm \ 96·\sqrt{21} \  )^2    \ \  \stackrel{?}{=} \  \   512· ( \ 448 \   \pm \ 96·\sqrt{21} \  ) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \  448 \   \pm \ 96·\sqrt{21}     \ \  \neq \  \   512 \ \ . $$

So we may conclude that the pairwise intersections of the three curves *do not* all fall on the same radial lines from the origin, and thus there is **no solution** to the given system of non-linear equations.

Interestingly, the second and third curves *nearly* meet tangentially.  The line $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ intersects the circle at $ \ x^2 \ = \ \frac52 \ \Rightarrow \ \left(\sqrt{\frac52} \ , \ \sqrt{\frac52} \ \approx \ 1.5811 \right) \ \ $ and intersects the "cubic curve" at  $ \ x^3 \ = \ 4 $ $ \Rightarrow \ \left(\sqrt[3]{4} \ , \ \sqrt[3]{4} \ \approx \ 1.5874 \right) \ \ , \ $ so the intersections of these two curves (in the first quadrant -- there is a second "diagonally symmetric" pair in the second and fourth quadrants ) lie on lines with reciprocal slopes *close* to $ \ 1 \ \ . \ $ (Those slopes are approximately $ \ m \ \approx \ 1.197 \ \ , \ \ m \ \approx \ 0.835 \ \ . \ ) $